# Differences between the immutable setter and traditional setter while set up an Option object

Tags: go, design-patterns, setter

After a time of investigating open source projects, I often see the pattern in the setting options for a class. (Let say "immutable method")

```
// list of possible options
type Options struct {
    Sampler sampler
    SpanKind int
}

// define an apply function. which will be called when really initialize an object
type Option func(*Options)

// for each option. Return an function to apply that specific option
func WithSpanKind(spanKind int) Option {
    return func(o *Options) {
        o.SpanKind = spanKind
    }
}

// then. we we build a new object, we just need to receive a list of option
func NewObject(options ...Option) Object {
     final := &Options{}
     // then apply each option to options
     for _, option := range options {
         option(final)
     }
     // then build an object based on the final object
}
```

Comparing to the above method, there is another way that using simple getter/setter.

```
func (o *Options) SetSpanKind(kind int) {
   o.spanKind = kind
}

// then. we we build a new object by using directly the Options object
func NewObject(option Options) Object {
}
```

My question is: What are the differences between those approaches and why the first approach always prefers in many open sources that I have read.

Noted: Here are some open sources with the line that implements the above pattern. Those open sources are initiated by Google, so maybe this pattern only specific to only Google, though.

- [Golang GRPC - DialOption](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/dialoptions.go#L113)
- [OpenCensus - TraceOption](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-go/blob/master/trace/trace.go#L158)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in Golang, the usage of getters is an anti-pattern. This option pattern is very well known. Setters and getters are not very common in the Golang space.

this option pattern has a little nice benefit you could pass multiple option functions into your builder or constructor and then iterating over all passed options to modify this options type like in your example

```
// then. we build a new object, we just need to receive a list of option
func NewObject(options ...Option) Object {
     final := &Options{}
     // then apply each option to options
     for _, option := range options {
         option(final)
     }
     // then build an object based on the final object
}
```

**Example constructor call:**

```
NewObject(optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD)
```

**Getters & Setters**

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters

You definitely read the effective go guidelines ->  https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html